# Cannot move object with MoveTowards in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to move my gun towards to a new position where the "Aim Position" is located at, but It won't work.
Here's my code:

```
    public Transform aimPosition;
    private float aimSpeed = 2f;

    private void GunManager()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, aimPosition.position, aimSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you call the GunManager() method in Update()? Does it work if you hold down the right mouse button?

Comment: Yes, I've called the GunManager() in the Update. And no, it doesn't work if I hold down the right mouse button.

Comment: Does code enters the if statement?

Comment: You could try Lerping towards the aiming position like so:
if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, aimPosition.position, aimSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: remove the if statement and see if it works

Comment: It still doesn't, no idea why...

Comment: show the code of whole class

Comment: I cannot send the whole as a comment so, here's the code of the class. https://dotnetfiddle.net/iyEyq3

Comment: Just call GunManager in Update and comment calling other functions

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: Are you sure AimPosition is set somewhere in the distance?

Comment: Yes, I am https://imgur.com/a/KMY5s8P

Comment: I've figured something out but I don't know why. So at the imgur you can see the Gun is a child of the "Guns". When I move it out of the "Guns" it works perfectly. But nowhere in my scripts nor inspector there's a thing that uses the "Guns" to do something. Why would it block the positioning?